# Moving buttons when keyboard is visible

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm using a ConstrantLayout with a Guideline, and a view(line) on top of that guideline. The Guideline is set to 85%. I also have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

This is how it looks like with keyboard hidden, the whole space above the white line  is my EditText

[image]

And this is how it looks like when keyboard is shown

[image]

I'm not exactly sure why, my guess is that the guideline after screen resizing needed to fit the keyboard is still set to 85% and it's too high to contain the `70dp` buttons below it.

How can i make it so that everything is like in the first image but above the keyboard when it is shown?

**EDIT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/root_ID"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/acceptButtonID"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:elevation="6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.85"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_private"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/DateButtonID"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_private"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/setButtonID"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_private"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_private"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/white_view_private"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_private" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_private"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please add some of your source code.

Comment: @AndréSousa added, there's literally nothing in my .java class, so it's not up there

Comment: Why didn't you align your buttons to the bottom of the layout and them align the other views above them?

Comment: @AndréSousa  You're right, that works. I guess i was kinda skeptical about setting up my layout with `dp` as margins and wanted to keep everything without margins and set up with guidelines `%` to keep it the same across different devices screens. But setting everything like you said works the same. One more question, is it bad to set up layouts like I did up there in the question? Not considering this keyboard problem?

Comment: If it works fast enough and does what you need/want it to do then it should be fine. If you had a lot of duplication you can always move the duplicated parts to styles.xml or create the views from a code loop and RecyclerView or whatever.